# How to perform a unique filter based on another table with variances?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of locations with lat/long attributes that i want to filter based on the lat/long's in another table. Essentially I am trying to find locations from table 1 near locations in table 2 using lat/long inputs. I figure that anything within +/- .5 decimal degrees is close enough. How can you filter with variances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your data is organized, but the examples below should get you started. The "min dist" column `C:C` gives the minimal distance between a point in table 1 `A:D` and a point in table 2 `F:G`.  The "count" column counts how many points in table 2 are within 0.5.

The heart of each is the expression `MMULT(($F$2:$G$6-A2:B2)^2,{1;1})`, which returns a vertical array in which each entry is the squared distance between the current point `A2:B2` and a point in table 2 `$F$2:$G$6`.  I assume you recognize the pythagorean formula, but if you want to follow the array formulas and matrix multiplication, I highly recommend Excel's "Evaluate Formula" tool (in the formulas tab).  (I do wish it would let me make the box larger, though -- you might want to start with small arrays for testing, since large ones are awkward to scroll through.)

**NOTE**: This is a simplification. This compares distance as if measured with a ruler on a Mercator projection, with the edges of the map at latitude +/- 180 degrees.  This may be good enough - I don't know.

[image]

[image]